# Are the subject and complement inverted in "Perched atop a high mountain on the other side [...] was a vast castle"?

Tags: subjects, subject-verb-inversion

In this example, are the subject and complement inverted, or could it be possible to understand that ‘The thing’ or something of the subject of verb ‘was’ is dropped?

> Perched atop a high mountain on the other side, its windows sparkling in the starry sky, was a vast castle with many turrets and towers.

Comment: I think it need the dummy "it" before "was".

Comment: No "dummy 'it'" is required in the sentence: **Perched atop a high mountain...was a vast castle...** is perfectly grammatical. Subject-Complement inversion: **A vast castle..., its windows sparkling..., was perched atop a high mountain**.

Comment: Yes, I'd say it was inversion, because an adjectival phrase (*perched...*) cannot normally be the subject of a sentence, which can be no other than *a vast castle...*.

Comment: @Cerberus's comment is the correct answer here.

Comment: @BillFranke: Not sure what your point is. Both inverted and uninverted forms are perfectly grammatical, whichever you consider the inversion.

Comment: @Tim: Normal word order is SVC: "Castle is perched". The sentence starting with "Perched" is the inversion: CVS. I said that both were perfectly grammatical and that no dummy "it" was necessary to make the inverted sentence grammatical. The OP wanted to know whether "_the subject and complement [are] inverted_". Cerberus and I are saying essentially the same thing: "YES: Subj-Complement inversion." That's all there is to it.

Comment: Stripping most of the words that are irrelevant to OP's question, all we have is *"Perched atop a mountain was a castle"* - which is just an unexceptional inversion of *"A castle was perched atop a mountain"*. I think it's General Reference.

Comment: Not unless this mythical "General Reference" that people keep referring to has a good account of the interactions between Right Node Raising and _There_-insertion.

Comment: @John: Well, I could have said *"**There was** a castle perched atop a mountain"*. Which looks to me pretty much like the (optional) "there" whose absence is bothering OP. Perhaps that's just coincidental similarity - but if it *is* the same "there", it still seems to me it's common knowledge/general reference among competent speakers that in OP's construction it's entirely a matter of style whether to include it or not.

Comment: Perched atop a mountain, there was a castle" would sound far less unusual to me. "In the box there is a map and a key" is a fairly usual ordering when you focus on listing contents and not the discovery. "In the box is a map and a key" would be highly irregular.

Comment: @SF. “Highly irregular?” Don’t be silly.  Down the street came a yellow fire-engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it may appear that the subject is "dropped" (also called "understood"), this is an example of inversion.

You could think of the sentence as simply: "Perched on a mountain was a castle,"
akin to the example sentence: "Lost among the old tables and chairs was the priceless Victorian desk," which is one of the 18 kinds of sentence inversions, called "intro -ed" described at:

http://www.testmagic.com/grammar/explanations/inversion.htm